# insert and update at the same time in mysql

Tags: mysql, function, sum

I want to insert and update two tables simultaneously in mysql.I have the table and the details below

```
CREATE TABLE Info
(
 id int auto_increment primary key, 
 BBP decimal(19,2) default "0.00" 

);


create table bill(Amount_paid decimal(19,2) default "0.00",
BAP decimal(19,2) default "0.00"
);    


INSERT INTO Info(BBP)
 VALUES
('30');


INSERT INTO bill(bid,Amount_paid,BAP)
SELECT i.id,
   10,
   i.BBP -
(SELECT COALESCE(sum(b.AMOUNT_PAID),0)+10
FROM bill b
WHERE bid = i.id)
 FROM info i
WHERE i.id = 1;

update info set BBP = (select BBP - coalesce(sum(Amount_paid),0) from bill WHERE id=1);
```

Basically the BBP was expected to be updated after inserting Amount_paid,but it only updates correctly upon first insertion of Amount_paid and incorrect after second and other insertion.
Every thing works as arranged, but the update query do not work as expected.Please i wish somebody teaches me where i am going wrong with my update query or any better query for doing this.Thanks for your help

Comment: What was expected and what did you get?

Comment: Does the `INSERT` query really work? There's no `bid` column in the `bill` table.

Comment: @GolezTrol I have updated my work above and  at Barmar there is bid in the bill table and the insert query work correctly, the update query do not work as expected.Thanks for your time.

Comment: You still haven't explained the difference between what you find 'correct' and which 'incorrect' behaviour actually happens. The only reference we have is not working code. It's like giving someone the misspelled word `caxe` and letting them guess whether it should have been 'cake', 'cape', 'axe' or 'monkey'.

Comment: I am sorry,but all that I am saying is, i want the BBP  to turn 20 after the insertion of the Amount_Paid thus 10 and follow the same sequence after every insertion.Please I hope its clear this time around.Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try

```
update info set BBP = BBP - (select coalesce(sum(Amount_paid),0) from bill) WHERE id=1;
```

Comment: PLEASE I HAVE BEEN BANNED FROM ASKING QUESTIONS ON THIS SITE, CAN SOMEBODY ASSIST ME FROM THE BAN.